# Print `from` variable in mutt's status_format

Tags: mutt

I keep multiple accounts in mutt by sourcing account files on certain keyboard shortcuts.

Each account, as part of it's configuration, sets `set from = "account@server.com"`.

Is there a way to print the current value of this variable in `status_format`, in order to easily know what account I'm currently using?

I've been skimming trough `muttrc` man page which shows the following sequences, but none seem to do what I need:

```
          %b     number of mailboxes with new mail *
          %d     number of deleted messages *
          %f     the full pathname of the current mailbox
          %F     number of flagged messages *
          %h     local hostname
          %l     size (in bytes) of the current mailbox *
          %L     size (in bytes) of the messages shown (i.e., which match the current limit) *
          %m     the number of messages in the mailbox *
          %M     the number of messages shown (i.e., which match the current limit) *
          %n     number of new messages in the mailbox *
          %o     number of old unread messages *
          %p     number of postponed messages *
          %P     percentage of the way through the index
          %r     modified/read-only/won't-write/attach-message indicator, according to $status_chars
          %s     current sorting mode ($sort)
          %S     current aux sorting method ($sort_aux)
          %t     number of tagged messages *
          %u     number of unread messages *
          %v     Mutt version string
          %V     currently active limit pattern, if any *
          %>X    right justify the rest of the string and pad with "X"
          %|X    pad to the end of the line with "X"
          %*X    soft-fill with character "X" as pad
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply include the variable you want to see in the status bar in `status_format`. For example:

```
  set status_format = "───[ Folder: %f ]───[%r%m messages%?n? (%n new)?%?d? (%d to delete)?%?t? (%t tagged)? ]───%>─%?p?( %p postponed )?─── $my_akr ───"
```

`$my_akr` is a variable that I set for each account differently, so I know, which account I am using. In your case you can substitute it with `$from` and the content of the variable `from` will be displayed in the status bar.

Comment: Hmm, the variable doesn't seem to get updated with `folder-hook` for example.

Comment: If `$my_akr` changes, you need to `source` the file that contains `status_format = ...` again.